# Generic method for 2 generic list?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 Lists `List<Class1>` and `List<Class2>`. I need to create a Method which will do some manupulations. how to create a Generic Method for passing List as Parameter.

```
Void ManipulateList(IList<obj> list)
{
    //statement;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to create a generic method:

```
public void ManipulateList<T>(IList<T> list)
```

If you want to be able to do things with the items in the lists, you'll probably want to add a generic constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Using generics is one option as suggested by SLaks. You could also use an Interface and have both `Class1` and `Class2` implement it, e.g.

```
public interface IClass { ... }

public class Class1 : IClass { ... }

public class Class2 : IClass { ... }
```

Then you method would be

```
void ManipulateList(IList<IClass> list)
```

Comment: Not quite; `IList<Class1>` cannot be converted to `IList<IClass>`.

Comment: @SLaks Couldn't you use an explicit cast on the method call?

Comment: @Charles380: No; that wouldn't be type-safe.  Mutable types cannot be covariant.